# Mocking a Post request with apache.http.client.HttpClient in Scala (2.11)

Tags: scala, mockito, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm trying to implement some unit tests for my HttpClient (in Scala 2.11); Here's my client:

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder
import org.apache.http.{HttpHeaders, HttpResponse}
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity

trait HttpClientFactory extends HttpClientBuilder {
  def create(): HttpClient
}

class HttpClientFactoryImpl extends HttpClientFactory {
  override def create(): HttpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
}
```

and then I wrote this method:

```
  def postRequest[T <: HttpClientFactory](postContent: String, endpoint: String, httpClientFactory: T): HttpResponse = {
    val client = httpClientFactory.create()
    val post = new HttpPost(endpoint)
    post.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(postContent))
    client.execute(post)
  }
```

I wanted to implement a basic unit test using Mockito, something like that:

```
import org.mockito.Matchers.any
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.Mockito.{mock, when}

class TestClient extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "test" should "do something" in {

    val postContent =
      """[
        | {"field1":"1",
        | "field2":"2",
        | "field3": "3"
        |},
        | {"field1":"10",
        | "field2":"20",
        | "field3": "30"
        |}]""".stripMargin

    val endpoint = "www.test.com"
    val post = new HttpPost(endpoint)
    post.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
    post.setEntity(new StringEntity(postContent))


    val mockHttpResponse = mock(classOf[HttpResponse])
    val mockStatusLine = mock(classOf[StatusLine])
    when(mockStatusLine.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.SC_OK)
    when(mockStatusLine.getReasonPhrase()).thenReturn("OK")

    when(mockHttpResponse.getStatusLine()).thenReturn(mockStatusLine)
    val httpClient = mock(classOf[HttpClient])
    when(httpClient.execute(post)).thenReturn(mockHttpResponse)

    val httpClientFactory = mock(classOf[HttpClientFactory])
    when(httpClientFactory.create()).thenReturn(httpClient)

    val result = postRequest[HttpClientFactory](postContent = postContent, endpoint = endpoint, httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory )

    result shouldEqual(mockHttpResponse)
    // or something like result.getStatusLine.getStatusCode shouldEqual(mockStatusLine.getStatusCode)
  }
}
```

But result is `null`, and that's my problem!

Any idea of what I am not doing right? Thanks. If you think of a better / simpler way of doing a simple HTTP Post request to a WebApi from a scala job, I take any suggestion.

Comment: Mostly when you get a `null` from a mock, it's because the mock is was not done correctly. Maybe changing `when(httpClient.execute(post))` for `when(httpClient.execute(eq(post)))` or `when(httpClient.execute(any[Post]))` could work.

Comment: The design of the method is a bit coupled with the http client. I would wrap the http client in a class that solves the reques/response and returns a DTO. Doing that the setup of the unit test for the method will be easier to do. Then you can test the class that uses the http client in an integraiton test

Comment: Your test has no value: you're mocking almost all what you want to test. To test a HTTP client, write a test that starts a lightweight http server which you control the responses and test against this server. There are several libraries to do that like mockserver.

Comment: @GastónSchabas thanks, `when(httpClient.execute(any[HttpPost]())).thenReturn(mockHttpResponse)` seems to work, but it does not really test anything right? I mean I would like to know my actual Post request has been sent.

Comment: if you wnat to validate that a method from a mock was called, you can use [verify](https://www.baeldung.com/scala/scalatest-mockito#3-verifying-execution-of-a-method). In this case, you are mocking almost anything, which means no logic is being validated. If you also validate that a method from an object that your code depends was invoked, the test will be less flexible and be tied to that object. An integration test using a real or a mock http server will be better in this case.